# live bind don't work after append

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone explains me why when i add an even number of squares the bind event won't work anymore ?

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#container").append("<div class=\"square\">xxxxxx</div> ").bind("click",function(e) {
            $(e.target).toggleClass( "change" );
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8W4JB/

Comment: your issue here is because as most jquery function, to keep chaining, the original matched set of elements is returned by append() method, not the appended element(s). So here, you are binding click event to #container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use event delegation.

Write:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $("#container").append("<div class=\"square\">xxxxxx</div> ");
});
$("#container").on("click", ".square", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("change");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8W4JB/2/)

[**More information here.**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1 for Event Delegation.but it can also be done without Event Delegation check my answer .

Comment: @TusharGupta thanks :) yes absolutely it is just one of the many ways

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/8W4JB/3/

```
$(document).on("click",".square",function(e) {
       $(e.target).toggleClass( "change" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8GveP/)</kbd>

Without Event Delegation.

Directly bind click event to the object to be added.

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var add =$("<div class=\"square\">xxxxxx</div>"); //make a jquery object of the element to added
    add.click(function(){ //attach click event to it
         $(this).toggleClass("change"); // toggleClass here
    }).appendTo('#container'); //append it to element with id container
});
```

[.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)